# Start Activity from Service always opens MainActivity

Tags: android

When I start an activty after receiving a GCM Message, it starts, next to the desired Activity, the MainActivity also. The problem is, I want to display the disired Activty (DialogActivity) as a Dialog-Box-Style Activity, so its background is transparent.

This is how I start the Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
  Log.d("GCM", "RECIEVED A MESSAGE");
  generateNotification(arg0, arg1.getStringExtra("message"));
  Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClass(this, DialogActivity.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(i); 
   }
```

This is the theme in the styles.xml

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
<item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
```

So the transparent Activity is laying on top of the MainActivity, which I want to avoid. It should show only the DialogActivity. Anyone knows help?

Comment: Dialog box is a floating window... so it will need some activity reference over which it will appear..!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I already solved it. For anyone in future facing the problem: 
Add FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK Flag to the Intent

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClass(this, DialogActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

According to the [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

Comment: Thanks, I had already come across this flag, but was looking for confirmation it did what I expected.